# Downloading Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: data-recovery

I've looked at the download page and it's not clear to me which download I use to enable me to create an Ubuntu Live CD.
I need the facility to try to recover data from a failing hard drive, using the instructions in this link: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/
Many thanks

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Any will do ...

Answer (score 0):

As [Ravexina](https://askubuntu.com/users/264781/ravexina) has suggested either of the desktop images will do for creating a live CD. The only difference would be is if you were installing Ubuntu on your hard drive which you are not as you are recovering data from it. You can then burn the image, mount the drive and copy the files onto an external disk following the rest of the instructions in the article.